# Error 404 when i try to add sharepoint lists.asmx web references

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint-2010

I have a Word document 2013 VisualStudio solution, and I tried to add a web reference "_vti_bin / search.asmx", but it shows me an error message **"Error downloading" http: // [web path] / _ vti_bin / ListData.svc request error with the following HTTP 404 steps: Not Found"**.
I'm use Sharepoint 2010.
I tried that, becouse i need attach my word document to an item adding by my code.
Please apologize my english. And thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Http error code 404 is page not found, you should check that the URL to the SVC is correct. Have you tried to browse it using the web browser?

Comment: well i can open _vti_bin/search.asmx  and _vti_bin/Lists.asmx in my browser with out problem however when i search vti_bin / ListData.svc, it show me empty page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking over there, I found the answer to my problem. It is necessary to put the port of the central administration so that the web service in the VS2010 can be recognized.
Like http://[webpath]**:10000**/_ vti_bin /search.asmx